# is it correct to nest fixed effects within random factors?

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, nested-data

[In this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70556/have-i-correctly-specified-my-model-in-lmer) @Ben Bolker wrote in his answer that for the interaction between `station` and `day` we could write `station+(1|day/station)`, but I don't understand how this is possible. In the OP, `day` is a random effect and `station` is fixed, but writing `(1|day/station)` means you are nesting `station` within `day`, in which case you are treating both `station` and `day` as random effects. My understanding is that nesting can only apply to random effects, according to @Tim's comment [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129293/is-my-nested-random-effect-model-non-hierarchical).

Also in @John's answer he mentions in the end that we could create a model like

```
lmer(y ~ station + (tow*day|station), data = dat)
```

but isn't this specifying `station` as a random effect (ie right side of | and within parentheses)? Shouldn't it rather be `lmer(y ~ station + (station|tow*day), data = dat)`?
Am I missing something?

Comment: (1|day/station) means (1|day) + (1|day:station), so it's a random effect of day and a random effect of day:station interaction. An interaction between random factor and a fixed factor is random. There is no random effect of station alone here (because station is random). So Ben's answer is correct.

Comment: Regarding (day|station), I don't see how it makes sense if station is fixed.

Comment: Thanks @amoeba. In the first comment you wrote "(because station is random)", but I think you meant "fixed", or am I wrong?

Comment: Regarding the (1|day/station), I was confused because I thought the / symbol always meant nested random effects like in the (1|school/class) situation in which school and class are both random effects. But if I understand it correctly, the (1|A/B) syntax could also mean random effect of A plus random effect of A-B interaction. This is somewhat confusing, how does lmer distinguish between nested random effects and random-fixed interaction effect?

Comment: (1) Yes, that's what I meant, sorry for confusion. (2) Yes, you are absolutely right, it can mean these two things. Lmer does not actually need to distinguish between them, because mathematically they are the same. I have once asked a similar question myself (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232109) but I am not happy with any of the answers. I should post my own answer there when I have time.

Comment: Thanks @amoeba. I look forward to your answer, I learn a lot from your posts :)

Comment: @amoeba are you still looking for a new (or amended) answer to this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232109

Comment: @RobertLong I honestly don't remember these discussions anymore :-) It's a been a while since I last thought about mixed models and repeated measures. But if you feel like updating/amending your answer in the linked thread, I'd be happy to re-read the whole discussion and will be happy to accept the answer if we think the question is resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is it correct to nest fixed effects within random factors?

No, it is not correct. However that is not what is happening in the first example:

```
... + station + (1|day/station) + ...
```

Here `station` is a fixed effect. As for the random effects structure, `station` is nested within `day`, but it is crucial to understand what this means:

```
(1|day/station)
```

is simply shorthand for

```
(1|day) + (1|day:station)
```

That is, we have random intercepts for the main effect of `day` and also random intercepts for the `day:station` interaction which means that `station` is free to vary randomly *within the levels of `day`*, which is what if means for a nested structure. `station` is not free to vary across all levels of `day`. Thus it is perfectly reasonable to have `+ station + (1|day/station) +`.

In the second example:

```
...+ station + (tow*day|station) + ...
```

this does not make sense because here, the main effect of `station` is specified as both random and fixed.